# find_all() returns None

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying get dollar's value in the google web page using beautiful soup. However, every call to find_all() function returns None. I don't know what I have to do. Help me, please!

code:

```
#Get dollar value   
from requests import *    
from bs4 import *    
r = get("https://www.google.com.br/#q=dolar")

if (r.status_code != 200):
  print ("conexão inválida")
else:
  print("Prosseguindo...")

  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

  print (soup.find_all("div", attrs = {"class" : "vk_ans vk_bk"}))
  print (soup.find_all("div", class_="vk_ans vk_bk"))
  print (soup.find_all(string="reais"))
  print (soup.find_all(class_="vk_ans"))
  print (soup.select("div.vk_ans.vk_bk"))
  print (soup.html.find_all("div", class_="vk_ans"))
  print (soup.select(".vk_ans vk_bk"))
```

I'm using python 3.4 and bs4.4.0
windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

`find_all` is returning `None` because it's not finding the elements you're requesting. Take into account that the HTML code that you see in your browser at `https://www.google.com.br/#q=dolar` may not be the same code that that `requests.get` is fetching.

You can easily check that by searching for the classnames in the string of the response:

```
In [13]: "vk_ans" in r.content
Out[13]: False
```

There's no trace of the string `vk_ans` in the code.

Also, two notes:

- Using Google to fetch the current value of the dollar is not a good idea. Try using some other website that does not change as frequently as Google's homepage.
- Do not use `from X import *`. You're poluting the global namespace of your script.

Comment: Thanks for the advices!
I found the problem: Google has JavaScript code, because this the request method don't read the page source.
I'm using selenium to solve this problem, however it open a web browser and it isn't cool.